# How to know the Post Data Object in block editor when I hit the Update button

Tags: widgets, block-editor

I need to see the Post Data that is being submitted when I hit the Update button of the block widget. I want to print this object in JavaScript console so that I can inspect the data.

The reason for this is that I am not able to save some information (selected checkbox values) of my widget.

I don't know whether I could explain the situation well! Hope this screenshot from block widget editor may be helpful!

[image]

PS: I have just gone through [How to detect when the user clicks the publish/update button in Gutenberg Editor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/416267/how-to-detect-when-the-user-clicks-the-publish-update-button-in-gutenberg-editor). It looks like there is no default way to do it. If so, is there any other way to accomplish this?